# How to force component reload

Tags: angular

I have a renderer2 that changes element on the template. The element has {{foo}} changed to "Hello world"

How to reset the element to display {{foo}}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer-setproperty-innerhtml-8gzjeg?file=app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div #el (click)="change()">{{foo}}</div>
  <button (click)="reset()">reset</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef;
  foo = 'click me'

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  change() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', '<h1>Hello world</h1>');
  }
  reset() {
    this.cdref.detectChanges()
  }

}
```

I already tried   this.cdref.detectChanges() it is not working

Comment: How about just... not doing that in the first place, and use a simpe *ngIf to display {{ foo }} or "Hello World"? Or to change the value of foo to "Hello World"?

Comment: You doing it more Jquery way by manipulating the DOM element but you can do it in Angular without interacting with navtive dom element.

Comment: This code is just a minimal reproducible version of my issue. My actual code has drag and drops features that require DOM manipulation. When the user drop after dragging, I want to reset component as if no DOM manipulation happened    @Niladri so there is no way to tell angular to redraw the component?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code this works for me :

```
import { Component, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div #el>{{foo}}</div>
  <button (click)="reset()">reset</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('el') el: ElementRef;
  foo = 'click me'

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }
  reset() {
    alert('inside this')
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', '<h1>Hello world</h1>');
    this.cdref.detectChanges()
  }

}
```

This worked, I have even edited the stackblitz example in the below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer-setproperty-innerhtml-8gzjeg?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

chang your `change` method and `reset` method

```
 addTag = this.renderer.createEl[][1]ement('h1');
  change() {
    const text = this.renderer.createText('Click here');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.addTag, text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement,this.addTag);
  }
  reset() {
    this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.addTag)
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer-setproperty-innerhtml-fqzjpg?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using renderer2, why don't you use **innerHTML** directive? It is much more easier and manage your code and as straightforward as it can be to understand.

Just Replace your code from this:-

```
<div #el (click)="change()">{{foo}}</div>
```

To this:-

```
<div #el (click)="change()" [innerHTML]="foo"></div>
```

---

Replace change method from this:-

```
change() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', '<h1>Hello world</h1>');
}
```

To this:-

```
change() {
    this.foo = '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
}
```

---

Also replace reset method from this:-

```
reset() {
    this.cdref.detectChanges()
  }
```

to this:-

```
reset() {
    this.foo = 'click me';
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer-setproperty-innerhtml-8gzjeg?file=app/app.component.ts